# Junit 5 integration test failed in maven 3.5.2 build

Tags: java, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin, openjdk-12

Junit5 integration runs standalone in intellij but fails in maven build with stacktrace as below.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superinterface check failed: class eu.nets.domain.QueuedMessage$HibernateProxy$1spaQq7T (in module eu.nets.queue.domain) cannot access class org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration (in unnamed module @0x72a21be8) because module eu.nets.queue.domain does not read unnamed module @0x72a21be8**
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.System$2.defineClass(System.java:2189) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.defineClass(MethodHandles.java:971) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingLookup$Dispatcher$ForJava9CapableVm.defineClass(ClassInjector.java:1685) ~[byte-buddy-1.9.16.jar:na]
    ... 125 common frames omitted
```

Please let me know if complete stacktrace is required

- tried with latest maven-surefire-plugin 3.0.0-M3
- ran with jdk11 as release

Here is the test:

```
@Test
void fetchMessagesViaAdapter() throws Exception {
    MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
            .post("/resend")
            .content("[\"queue1\"]")
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
                                 .andExpect(status().isOk())
                                 .andReturn();
    String resultDOW = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
    assertAll(
            () -> assertNotNull(resultDOW),
            () -> assertEquals("success", resultDOW));
}
```

Comment: Are you using java modules feature ?

Comment: i used java 9 modularazation.

Answer (score 0):

> module eu.nets.queue.domain does not read unnamed module

Based on the error that you get, you can add the following VM option to resolve this -

```
--add-reads eu.nets.queue.domain=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering.Its been so long that i am not even able to replicate the issue